# MediaPlayer воспроизведение с качельки громкости

Tags: java, android

Как с  кнопки громкости сделать управление воспроизведением?
Когда воспроизводится трек кнопка была не активна.Трек закончился снова стала активна.Вот код:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

            sounds = new int[] {
                R.raw.muz1, R.raw.muz2, R.raw.muz3, R.raw.muz4, R.raw.muz5, R.raw.muz6, R.raw.muz6, R.raw.muz7
            };

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[index]);
            mp.setLooping(false);
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    mp.release();
                    if (index < sounds.length - 1) {
                        index++;


                        return;

                    }
                }
            });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто проверяйте в самом начале обработчика нажатия что что-то играется и ничего в таком случае не делайте.

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите отключить аппаратную кнопку управления звуком на время исполнения композиции?

Comment: В таком случае, это противоречит правилам хорошей практики написания приложений под Андроид. Не рекомендуется менять действие аппаратных кнопок на такие, для которых они не предназначены, либо отключать их. Пользователь может прийти в замешательство от того, что он не может сделать привычное действие, в данном случае уменьшить громкость во время воспроизведения трека. Такой функционал уже сам по себе несет ошибку в логику приложения. Не стоит издеваться над пользователем.